# react-redux handling multiple requests

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using redux + react-redux + react-native

There are times (when typing on a text field for example) that multiple requests are sent to the server. How can I handle this case, so that only the last one is processed on the client?

I've read fetch doesn't have a promise reject, so I'm not sure if there is a way to differ promises, or a flow or middleware to handle this correctly in redux, like keeping track of all requests order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) or [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable), they internally use RxJS and can cancel previous actions, like when you use takeLatest, only the last action will get completely executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have :

- an action that changes the state of the value of the textfield
- an other action that makes the request on submit (or using debounce on the onChange)

Here is an example: https://topheman.github.io/react-es6-redux/ (try the dev version, you'll have access to redux-devtools & sourcemaps)

Usefull resource if you don't know about debounce : https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Thanks. I have an action that stores the text while it changes and an async thunk for searching that gets triggered if the user stops more than 400ms while typing (sort of a debounce). However in react-native it is usual that requests don't come back in order.

For example first search goes for "country", second goes for "country songs", if "country" search returns after second, I end up rendering the wrong search. If I could only reject the first request, or know which one I'm talking about.